# Customized layer

Tags: lambda, layer

I'm trying to build a voting Ensemble Learning constructed by 3 CNNs. The structure is shown in the pic.

My problem is that I wish 3 different CNNs could process the image differently before training.
For example, I wish CNN1 could use Weber's local descriptor to classify images.

I have tried to add a lambda layer in Mobilenet_V2 after the input layer, but it not works.

Can anyone help, Please?

```
# Create the base model from the pre-trained model MobileNet V2
IMG_SHAPE = IMG_SIZE + (3,)
base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=IMG_SHAPE,
                                               include_top=False,
                                               weights='imagenet')
image_batch, label_batch = next(iter(train_dataset))
feature_batch = base_model(image_batch)
print(feature_batch.shape)
global_average_layer = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()
feature_batch_average = global_average_layer(feature_batch)
print(feature_batch_average.shape)
prediction_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
prediction_batch = prediction_layer(feature_batch_average)
print(prediction_batch.shape)
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

# Define the Weber function
def weber(grayscale_image):
    grayscale_image = grayscale_image.astype(np.float64)
    grayscale_image[grayscale_image == 0] = np.finfo(float).eps
    neighbours_filter = np.array([
        [1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 1]
    ])
    convolved = convolve2d(grayscale_image, neighbours_filter, mode='same')
    weber_descriptor = convolved - 8 * grayscale_image
    weber_descriptor = weber_descriptor / grayscale_image
    weber_descriptor = np.arctan(weber_descriptor)
    return weber_descriptor
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(160, 160, 3))
weber_layer = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(weber)(inputs)
x = data_augmentation(weber_layer)
x = preprocess_input(x)
x = base_model(x, training=False)
x = global_average_layer(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
outputs = prediction_layer(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
```